# Set a ListView scrolled to bottom at app start? (android)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I dont want to scroll it (becz i think it takes time and perfomance to scroll). I want to set it already scrolled to bottom at the start of the activity like whatsapp.

How could this be done?

Comment: A correctly implemented ListView will not hinder your performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `ListView` to be **always** scrolled at the bottom even on updating, you can add these attributes to the list:

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Otherwise use :

```
listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

listview.setSelection(LastItemIndexInListView);

LastItemIndexInListView : size of listview - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         listView.scrollTo(0, listView.getBottom());
     }
});
```

Give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
    }
});
```

This should work for you